# How to join one table with another join in JPA criteria builder?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Below is the query which i want to convert into JPA criteria builder.

```
SELECT a.id,a.marker_group_id,a.name FROM alert a
LEFT JOIN marker_group mg ON a.marker_group_id = mg.id
LEFT JOIN marker m ON mg.id = m.marker_group_id
where m.latitude = '32.985173502462686' AND m.longitude='-96.89707056619227';
```

I already tried like this below, but I got confused like how to go ahead

```
Root<Alert> root;
Join<Alert, MarkerGroup> markerGroupJoin = root.join("markerGroup", JoinType.LEFT);
```

here how can I join marker m with existing left join marker group mg.

Here Alert table and marker table has marker group

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: `markerGroupJoin.join(...)`.

Comment: Root<Marker> mroot = query.from(Marker.class);

Predicate markerJoin = cb.equal(mroot.get("markerGroup"),markerGroupJoin.get("name") );


I tried this, is it right?

Comment: In your "JPQL" you are joining a field "marker", so that has to be the field joined in JPA Criteria. If "marker" is a field of the candidate then that should be `root.join("marker", JoinType.LEFT)` ... not joining on "markerGroupJoin". But then, since you don't post your entities, it is all guesswork ...